# Set meson variable using Current Directory /Project Directory

Tags: variables, meson-build

I have a meson project on the path `/home/$user/foo/bar/project`. I want to set a variable sys_root in a cross_compile.txt file. I don't want to hard code the path in case my project moves to another directory.

I don't want <strike>sys_root = /home/$user/foo/bar/project/prefix</strike>. I want i
`sys_root = project-dir/foo/bar/prefix`

What is the variable for the current directory with the cross_compile.txt in case it is in the same directory with the meson.build file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing that currently exists is the `[constants]` section of the machine files, you can write something like:

```
[constants]
root_dir = "/home/$user"
```

and

```
[properties]
sys_root = root_dir + "/project_dir/..."
```

And layer them together with `meson setup builddir --cross-file contants.ini --cross-file main.ini`